# Refresh desktop icons

Tags: unity, mount, windows, desktop-environments, desktop-icons

I have used mount --bind to mirror my Windows desktop folder to Ubuntu. I have set it up to mount on boot but the desktop does not refresh the icons so I have to logout and log back in to make the icons appear.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I am running 12.10 if that changes anything.

Also I have tried killall nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

Also right click in the applications folder on the .desktop icon and add to the desktop folder.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to log out. Nautilus is responsible for rendering desktop icons, so just open a terminal (`Ctrl+Alt+t`), and then type `killall nautilus`. Your desktop icons will disappear, but they should come back shortly. If they don't come back, you can type `Alt+F2` and then type `nautilus` to get the icons back (don't run nautilus in the terminal because it'll just get killed again when you close the terminal).

Comment: I tried that... it only closes the current windows open... and running nautilus only opens a new window. I am currently running 12.10 if that changes anything.

Comment: This worked for me.  However the icons only remained visible while the terminal was up.  I suggest running "nohup nautilus &" in order to close the terminal, and keep the icons visible.